# Making cv2.createTrackbar specified step size and discard certain values

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have been running the trackbar program from the OpenCV documentation. 
Here is the code:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 def nothing(x):
    pass

 # Create a black image, a window
 img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
 cv2.namedWindow('image')

 # create trackbars for color change
 cv2.createTrackbar('R','image',5,255,nothing)
 cv2.createTrackbar('G','image',5,255,nothing)
 cv2.createTrackbar('B','image',5,255,nothing)

 # create switch for ON/OFF functionality
 switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
 cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'image',0,1,nothing)

 while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
       break

    # get current positions of four trackbars
    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','image')
    **if r%4 == 0 and r >0 and r <255:
       pass**
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','image')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'image')

    if s == 0:
      img[:] = 0
    else:
      img[:] = [b,g,r]

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want the trackbar step size to be 4, i.e. as the range is set to 0-255, I want values that are divisible by 4. I have adjusted this thing in the `nothing` callback like this:

```
def nothing(x):
    if x > 0 and x <255 and x % 4 ==0 
       pass
```

Also I have also added a code (bold one), but this is also not working
Anyone with a solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is no argument in OpenCV to specify the step size, you can modify your algorithm to incorporate the same:

Currently you have a trackbar that can move from 1-255. You're reading its position as it is, but you're only interested in the values {4,8,12,16...}

You can reduce the range of your trackbars from [1-255] to [1-63], as `int(255/4)=63`

Then when you receive a trackbar position, you can multiply it by 4, thus your trackbar range will look like:

{1,2,3,4...63} x 4 = {4,8,12,16...252}

You can do this in code as shown:

```
cv2.createTrackbar('R','image',1,63,nothing)
#create trackbar with reduced range
...

 r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','image')
 r=4*r
 #read reduced range and scale it up
```

Answer (score 3):

Before this:

```
 img[:] = [b,g,r]
```

in the else statement you can simply put a condition :

```
 if b%4==0 and g%4==0 and r%4==0:
```

then write the above statement.Hope it helps.